# Why .toISOString() gives different time?

Tags: javascript

Why this sample give me 22 number instead client 23 number:

```
console.log(new Date().toISOString());
```

Output is: `2019-01-22T22:58:46.606Z`

Client side time:

[image]

Comment: It's because the output is Greenwich Time, and you are in another timezone.

Comment: You're getting a date in the UTC time zone (that's what "Z" means at the end of the time string).

Comment: How to store date in my local time in session storage to convert then to Date?

Comment: One choice would be as the epoch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `toISOString()` method always outputs the time in UTC. From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString):

> The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix "Z".

In this case, the date is still the 22nd in UTC but, in your timezone, it's already the 23rd.

The `Date` object you have here is still in your local timezone, though. It just happens that the `toISOString()` method *always* outputs a UTC representation. If you do the following, you should see the date you're expecting:

```
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString()) // "1/22/2019, 3:14:18 PM" for me (US Pacific Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

`toISOString()` returns a date/time in ISO format with timezone as UTC +0.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to what's already been offered. You still need to be careful about using the Date() method. It can generate different dates depending on what you give it.

```
//This outputs midnight (12:00AM) on January 22nd in the UTC timezone
new Date('2019-01-22').toISOString() // output: "2019-01-22T00:00:00.000Z"

//This outputs 5:00AM on January 22nd in the UTC timezone because my PC is in the
//Eastern Standard timezone and I used a different format for my date string.
new Date('01/22/2019').toISOString() // output: "2019-01-22T05:00:00.000Z"
```