# Javascript date method toISOString doesn't return proper date

Tags: javascript, date, iso

I had an issue with Date:

I want to get the last day of month

```
const date = new Date();
const lastDayOfMonth = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
console.log(lastDayOfMonth); //Wed Nov 30 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (temps universel coordonné)
console.log(lastDayOfMonth.toISOString()) //2022-11-30T00:00:00.000Z
```

The same code I've run on other computer's browser
I found the same result **except** `console.log(lastDayOfMonth.toISOString()) //2022-11-29T00:00:00.000Z`, I got `29` instead of `30`?

I don't know why? if anyone knows, could explain us more why Date behave differently on different browser...

Comment: The `Z` in the ISO string means that it is in the UTC time zone. The `Date` constructor uses the time zone of the computer that it runs on, so the hours in difference between that time zone and UTC will be subtracted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why .toISOString() gives different time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54317726/why-toisostring-gives-different-time)

Comment: @Ivar from the first `console.log()` it appears that the OP is at GMT+0, or UTC anyway. The real question is why day 0 in December is coming back the 29th of November.

Comment: When you do the *exact* block of code on the "other computer", what does the **first** `console.log()` print?

Comment: Also, what time of day is it there? The `new Date()` call will give you a date with the *current local time* in the hours/minutes/seconds.

Comment: Just a note:  The constructor pattern your using `(y,m,d)` is a locale date constructor, your then asking for a `UTC` they can be different.  If you want to construct a UTC time you will need to do the string constructor `'YYYY-MM-DD'`

Comment: @Pointy (I assume you already know, but just in case) Numbers < 1 in the constructor will be subtracted from the given date, so it _should_ return November 30th local time. I'm at UTC+1 and `.toISOString()` returns `2022-11-29T23:00:00.000Z`, which is to be expected because UTC is 1 hour behind on my time zone. I assume that OP just noticed the `29` on a different machine and changed it in that comment. I doubt the `T00:00:00.000Z` is accurate.

Comment: @Ivar yea all I can guess is that the local time zone on the "other" system is different, and he's doing this around midnight local time.

Comment: @Pointy OP is omitting the hours/minutes/seconds parameters of the Date constructor which default to `0`, so it doesn't really matter at what time they are doing it. The Date will be at midnight local time.